# KeyError:'records' in AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda

I am trying to create Lambda that convert an incoming XML message from kinesis stream to JSON and Stores in S3.

I have created a lambda package and imported as part of Lambda creation. After creation of lambda when I test from Lambda Console I get error:

```
[ERROR] KeyError: 'records'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/kinesis_streaming_s3_v5.py", line 19, in lambda_handler
    for record in event ['records']:
```

Find below code snippet:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import xmltodict
import pprint
import boto3
import datetime
import json

s3_client = boto3.client ('s3')
s3_resource = boto3.resource ('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for record in event ['records']:
        with open (record) as xml_str:
            for l in xml_str:
                file_suffix = datetime.datetime.now ()
                split_data = base64.b64decode (l ['data'])
                print (split_data)
                xml_data = split_data.replace ("\\n", "").replace (")", "").replace ("'", "").replace ("\\t","").replace (" <?xml", "<?xml")
                print (xml_data)
                CustomerJson = pprint.pformat (json.dumps (xmltodict.parse (xml_data)), indent=100, width=1500)
                print (CustomerJson)
                xmlfilename = 'customer_{}'.format (file_suffix)
                print (xmlfilename)
                s3_client.put_object (Body=CustomerJson, Bucket='XXXXXXXX', Key='json/' + xmlfilename + '.json',ACL='public-read')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Kinesis Data Stream makes the event such as

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "kinesis": {
        "partitionKey": "partitionKey-03",
        "kinesisSchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "data": "SGVsbG8sIHRoaXMgaXMgYSB0ZXN0IDEyMy4=",
        "sequenceNumber": "49545115243490985018280067714973144582180062593244200961",
        "approximateArrivalTimestamp": 1428537600
      },
      "eventSource": "aws:kinesis",
      "eventID": "shardId-000000000000:49545115243490985018280067714973144582180062593244200961",
      "invokeIdentityArn": "arn:aws:iam::EXAMPLE",
      "eventVersion": "1.0",
      "eventName": "aws:kinesis:record",
      "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:kinesis:EXAMPLE",
      "awsRegion": "ap-northeast-2"
    }
  ]
}
```

where the `records` is actually `Records`.